# Java Morse Code Translator

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to the Java programming language, and one of the projects I am working on is a Java morse code translator (Morse to English and vice versa.) Below is one method for translating English strings to Morse code.

```
public static void StringtoMorse(String str){
    char Alphabet [] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' '};
    String MorseCode [] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "|"};


    for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet.length; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j ++){
            if (Alphabet[i] == (str.charAt(j))){
                System.out.print(MorseCode[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

For some cases, the program works: if I enter 'a', it returns '.-' correctly, but for some other cases, it doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: What other cases doesn't it work for?

Comment: This sort of thing is all over StackOverflow. Do a search.

Comment: Show the results of what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops are not in the correct order. Change your loops to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++){ //in your code, this is the inner for and it should be the outer one as it is here

        for(int j = 0; j < Alphabet.length; j++){ //same for this one

            if(input.charAt(i) == Alphabet[j]){

                System.out.print(MorseCode[j] + " || ");

            }//end if 

         }//end inner for
}//end outer for
```

The way you were implementing it was wrong according to your needs. It was actually working fine, but it was **showing the morse values sorted alphabetically**. If the input was "abc", then the output would be correct since the input was already sorted alphabetically. But if the input was "cab", the input would equally be "abc" in morse.

You were basically departing from the first char of the alphabet array, and checking if any of the chars from your input was equal to that first alphabet char, and so on. So if the input had an 'a' for example, no matter where that 'a' was inside that word, it was always going to be showed at the first position, since it was the first letter being checked.

So if you do it my way, you're departing from the first char in the input, and looking where that char is inside the Alphabet.

Comment: Thanks! Your code worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think best way to achieve what you want would be to use `HashMap<Character, String>` . Put every alphabet character to HashMap as key and every Morse code as value. And then you will be able to get every Morse value like this

```
    Character alphabet [] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' '};
    String morseCode [] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "|"};
    HashMap<Character, String> morseCodes = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < Alphabet.length; i++)
    {
        morseCodes.put(alphabet[i], morseCode[i]);
    };
```

And do not forget to cast every character to lowercase when getting Morse value from HashMap, since you've put every character as lowercase.
And try to used to java naming conventions. Variable names shout start lowercase. It is not a crime to not obey to this rule, but for others it will be confusing.